# How can I modify my code to get data from an array of objects in C#?

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public partial class Content
{

    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public int ContentTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] Version { get; set; }

    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }

}
```

and the following code:

```
var myData = new[] {
   "Content 1",
   "Content 2",
   "Content 3" 
};

var contents = myData.Select(e => new Content
{
   Title = e,
   Text = "xx",
   ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
}
```

How can I modify this so I can specify both the "Title" and some small sample "Text" in the myData array. I was thinking about using an array of objects but I am not quite sure how to set this up.

Comment: Lambdas are very powerful - they can take multiple parameters, they can reference and modify external variables, etc. Try some things you think might work and you may be surprised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the syntax for that:

```
var myData = new List<Content>
            {
              new Content{Title = "Content 1", Text = "xx", ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now},
              new Content{Title = "Content 2", Text = "AB", ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now},
              new Content{Title = "Content 3", Text = "CC", ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now}
            };
```

Comment: Can you show me how I would fill the data into contents using the lambda. I am not sure how to do that with it in an object now.

Answer (score 1):

How about you use Tuple?

```
        var myDatas = new[]
        {
            new Tuple<string, string, DateTime>("Title", "Example", DateTime.Now),
            new Tuple<string, string, DateTime>("Title2", "Example", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)),
            new Tuple<string, string, DateTime>("Title3", "Example", DateTime.Now.AddDays(1))
        };

        var contents = myDatas.Select(e => new Content
        {
            Title = e.Item1,
            Text = e.Item2,
            ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
        });
```